# Modifying elements of an Arraylist and adding that to another ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to solve Pascal's triangle. I have two snippets of code written in Java, first one creates `inner` ArrayList few times and works fine for me.

But in second version of the code, if I modify `inner` ArrayList, it also modifies the `outer` ArrayList and doesn't give me the expected result. Can anyone please explain why does it happen?

Also, using `inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();` statement is not a good approach as I am using that few times in a short function. How can I get rid of that? Any explanation and suggestion would be really appreciated!

Way 1: works but not efficient!

```
  public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> generate(int a) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if (a==0) return outer;

        inner.add(1);
        outer.add(inner);

        if(a==1) return outer;

        inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        inner.add(1);
        inner.add(1);
        outer.add(inner);

        inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();    
        if (a==2) return outer;


        for (int i=2; i<a; i++){
            inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            inner.add(1);
            for(int j=1; j<i; j++){
                inner.add(outer.get(i-1).get(j-1)+outer.get(i-1).get(j));
            }
            inner.add(1);
            outer.add(inner);          
        }

        return outer;          
  }
```

Way 2: does not work!

```
  public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> generate(int a) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if (a==0) return outer;

        inner.add(1);
        outer.add(inner);
        inner.clear();

        if(a==1) return outer;

        inner.add(1);
        inner.add(1);
        outer.add(inner);
        inner.clear();
        if (a==2) return outer;

        for (int i=2; i<a; i++){
            inner.add(1);
            for(int j=1; j<i; j++){
                inner.add(outer.get(i-1).get(j-1)+outer.get(i-1).get(j));
            }
            inner.add(1);
            outer.add(inner);
            inner.clear();
        }

        return outer;    
  }
```

Comment: where you want to Modifying elements?

Comment: I am reusing inner ArrayList, did you get that?

Comment: @SMAlMamun Are you sure that you are reusing it? Look at your code more closely.

Comment: @NathanielJones when I am clearing it, I am not creating anything new in second version of code!

Comment: @SMAlMamun First, you are creating new ones in your for loop, and second, it is the clearing that causes the problem.

Comment: @SMAlMamun I see that you edited your code. However, your problem still exists becaue `add()` does not do what you think it does. It does not create a copy, and even if it did, it would have to use `new` internally to do so, so it would not be more efficient. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want add multiple `ArrayList<Integer>` objects to your outer `ArrayList`, you *must* call `new ArrayList<Integer>()` for each one. Your second version is not more efficient. In your second version, you clear every `ArrayList<Integer>` that you make, which means that all of your lists are empty.

Remember that this:

```
outer.add(inner);
inner.clear();
```

and this:

```
inner.clear();
outer.add(inner);
```

are equivalent to each other. Both sets of instructions will empty the inner `ArrayList` and add it to the outer `ArrayList`.